# Calculate majority using circular moving window on categorical data in R

Tags: r, raster, categorical-data

I'm trying to calculate the majority value in a categorical raster data set in R, for example using land cover data. This would be similar to the focal statistics tool in ArcGIS using the majority statistic. I am able to calculate the majority land cover type using a rectangular moving window and the modal function:

```html
library(raster)

# create data
r <- raster(nrows = 120, ncol = 120, xmn=0)
r[] <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

a<-focal(r, w=matrix(1,3,3), fun=modal)    # 3x3 moving window
plot(a)
```

However, when I apply a focal weight to define my circular moving window, the output values appear to be treated as continuous numbers and not discrete values, even if I convert the raster to a factor:

```html
#convert to a factor factor
r.f<-as.factor(r)
#set up window
fw <- focalWeight(r.f, 4.5, type='circle')
#apply focal fxn
r.f.focal<-focal(r.f, w=fw, fun=modal, na.rm=TRUE)
```

It appears zeros might be added into the analysis and that is creating the problem. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Your rasters crs is currently in "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0". If you reduce d in focalWeight to something like "0.001" the result looks kind of okay.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippGärtner. I did not pay attention to the crs - it was just what I worked up for a reproducible example. I still have the problem when I perform the focal function on my projected land cover data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be fixed if **`d`** (which is now 4.5) is an integer. Your defined radius should be based on cell counts (1,2,3,...,n). However, still, the output will be in floating format as each `xij` in the kernel is a floating point with sum of `1`. To achieve an integer output there is also a third option.

```
library(raster)

set.seed(070319)
# create data
r <- raster(nrows = 120, ncol = 120, xmn=0)
r[] <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
a<-focal(r, w=matrix(1,3,3), fun=modal)    # 3x3 moving window

par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(r)
plot(a)
```

[image]

```
#set up window
fw <- focalWeight(r, 4, type='circle')
#apply focal fxn
r.f.focal<-focal(r, w=fw, fun=modal, na.rm=TRUE)

par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(r)
plot(r.f.focal)
```

[image]

for integer output you can also do this:

```
#set up window
fw <- ceiling(focalWeight(r, 4, type='circle'))#for integer output
#apply focal fxn
r.f.focal<-focal(r, w=fw, fun=modal, na.rm=TRUE)

par(mfrow=c(1,2), oma=c(0,0,0,1)) 
plot(r)
plot(r.f.focal)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Majid. The ceiling function was the key ingredient for the integer data. I did notice it's important to check the architecture/shape of the fw. If there are too many zero's in the corner extents, the focal function will introduce zero's into the output. I assume the focal fxn will then miss pixels and assign a zero?

Comment: No worries Tim. Yes, that is true! It could be even worse if you have zeros in your input data (i.e. 'r[] <- sample(0:3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)'). Get around it by replacing zeros in `fw` with NA (as in `fw[fw == 0] <- NA`).
If you have more questions please post a new question and I am happy to help :).